# Installation skipped SQL Server with wix

Tags: c#, installation, wix

This is my code I want to install SQL Server Express with my msi package. But when installing, it skipped SQL Server and only installed the rest of the msi package. And when uninstall, it can't uninstall SQL Server and throws an error.

What is my error? Please help me. I want to install SQL Server Express and install msi and using Windows authentication for contact.

```
<?define InstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER" ?> 
<?define InstanceNameExpress = "SQLEXPRESS" ?> 
<?define ServerInstall="SomeCondition" ?>

<?define InstanceName = "YOUR_INSTANCE" ?>
<?define SqlWebLink = http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/2/9/529FEF7B-2EFB-439E-A2D1-A1533227CD69/SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe ?>

<util:RegistrySearch
  Id="SqlInstanceKeyFound"
  Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL" Win64="yes" Value="$(var.InstanceName)"
  Result="exists" Variable="SqlInstanceKeyFound" />
<util:RegistrySearch
  Id="SqlInstanceKey"
  Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL" Win64="yes" Value="$(var.InstanceName)"
  Variable="SqlInstanceKey" After="SqlInstanceKeyFound"  Condition="SqlInstanceKeyFound" />
<util:RegistrySearch
  Id="SqlInstanceFound"
  Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\[SqlInstanceKey]"
  Result="exists" Variable="SqlInstanceFound" Win64="yes" After="SqlInstanceKey" Condition="SqlInstanceKeyFound" />
<util:RegistrySearch
  Id="SqlVersion"
  Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\[SqlInstanceKey]\Setup" Value="Version"
  Variable="SqlVersion" After="SqlInstanceKey" Win64="yes" Condition="SqlInstanceFound" />



    <Chain>
<!--
<PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx47Web"/>

     -->


      <PackageGroupRef Id="Sql2012Express"/>


      <RollbackBoundary />

      <MsiPackage Id="MyApplication" SourceFile="$(var.SetupProject1.TargetPath)" DisplayInternalUI="yes" Compressed="yes" Vital="yes"/>

    </Chain>
  </Bundle>

  <Fragment>

    <PackageGroup Id="Sql2012Express">
  <!--
    SQL Server 2012 Express - Install new instance
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx
    SQL Server Express requires WIndows Installer 4.5
    RepairCommand="/ACTION=Repair /INSTANCENAME=$(var.InstanceName) /Q /HIDECONSOLE"
  -->
      <ExePackage Id="Sql2012Express"
        DisplayName="SQL Server 2012 Express"
        Cache="yes"
        Compressed="yes"
        PerMachine="yes"
        Permanent="no"
        Vital="yes"
        Name="Redist\SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe"
        SourceFile=".\prerequisites\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe"
        DownloadUrl="$(var.SqlWebLink)"
        InstallCommand='/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /HIDECONSOLE /INSTANCEID="$(var.InstanceName)" /ACTION="Install" /FEATURES=SQLENGINE /HELP="False" /INDICATEPROGRESS="False" /QUIET="True" /QUIETSIMPLE="False" /ERRORREPORTING="False" /SQMREPORTING="False" /INSTANCENAME="$(var.InstanceName)" /AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Manual" /ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic" /ISSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" /ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic" /ASCOLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS" /ASDATADIR="Data" /ASLOGDIR="Log" /ASBACKUPDIR="Backup" /ASTEMPDIR="Temp" /ASCONFIGDIR="Config" /ASPROVIDERMSOLAP="1" /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic" /FILESTREAMLEVEL="0" /ENABLERANU="True" /SQLCOLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="True" /TCPENABLED="0" /NPENABLED="0" /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled" /RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic" /RSINSTALLMODE="FilesOnlyMode" /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="tomsoN_admin_1032"'


        UninstallCommand="/Action=Uninstall /INSTANCENAME=$(var.InstanceName) /FEATURES=SQL /Q "
        DetectCondition="NOT (SqlInstanceFound AND (SqlVersion &lt; v15.0.1000.169))"
        InstallCondition="NOT (SqlInstanceFound AND (SqlVersion &lt; v15.0.1000.169))">
        <ExitCode Value ="3010" Behavior="forceReboot" />
        <dep:Provides DisplayName="Net2 SQL Server 2012 Express" Key="SQLServer2012Express,$(var.InstanceName)" Version="11.0.3000.0" />
      </ExePackage>
```

this is my output.

```
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i001: Burn v3.11.1.2318, Windows v10.0 (Build 16299: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\orhan12\AppData\Local\Temp\{F1FD8805-8AE6-4488-BE25-09A17DC0E8F6}\.cr\FlownetMasterSetup.exe
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=C:\Users\orhan12\source\repos\PropulsimCS\Propulsim\FlownetMasterSetup\bin\Debug\FlownetMasterSetup.exe -burn.filehandle.attached=608 -burn.filehandle.self=612'
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\orhan12\source\repos\PropulsimCS\Propulsim\FlownetMasterSetup\bin\Debug\FlownetMasterSetup.exe'
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\orhan12\source\repos\PropulsimCS\Propulsim\FlownetMasterSetup\bin\Debug\'
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\orhan12\AppData\Local\Temp\FLOWNETMASTER_20180924114204.log'
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'FLOWNETMASTER'
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Melina-Aero'
[2074:2EB8][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i000: Setting numeric variable 'WixStdBALanguageId' to value 1033
[2074:2EB8][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '1.0.0.1'
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i100: Detect begin, 2 packages
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i000: Registry value not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL', Value = 'YOUR_INSTANCE'
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i000: Setting numeric variable 'SqlInstanceKeyFound' to value 0
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i052: Condition 'SqlInstanceKeyFound' evaluates to false.
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i052: Condition 'SqlInstanceKeyFound' evaluates to false.
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i052: Condition 'SqlInstanceFound' evaluates to false.
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i000: Setting string variable 'Netfx4x64FullVersion' to value '4.7.03062'
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i000: Setting string variable 'Netfx4FullVersion' to value '4.7.03062'
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i102: Detected related bundle: {07cab931-fdbc-4f40-8f72-71b95e6e83af}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.1, operation: None
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i102: Detected related bundle: {38cbc870-30a1-42ac-aea1-aa610d5080c1}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.1, operation: None
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i052: Condition 'NOT (SqlInstanceFound AND (SqlVersion < v15.0.1000.169))' evaluates to true.
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i101: Detected package: Sql2012Express, state: Present, cached: None
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i101: Detected package: MyApplication, state: Absent, cached: None
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:04]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[2074:2EB8][2018-09-24T11:42:06]i000: Setting numeric variable 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' to value 1
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:06]i200: Plan begin, 2 packages, action: Install
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:06]i052: Condition 'NOT (SqlInstanceFound AND (SqlVersion < v15.0.1000.169))' evaluates to true.
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:06]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_MyApplication' to value 'C:\Users\orhan12\AppData\Local\Temp\FLOWNETMASTER_20180924114204_000_MyApplication_rollback.log'
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:06]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_MyApplication' to value 'C:\Users\orhan12\AppData\Local\Temp\FLOWNETMASTER_20180924114204_000_MyApplication.log'
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:06]i201: Planned package: Sql2012Express, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:06]i201: Planned package: MyApplication, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:06]i207: Planned related bundle: {07cab931-fdbc-4f40-8f72-71b95e6e83af}, type: Upgrade, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, dependency: None
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:06]i207: Planned related bundle: {38cbc870-30a1-42ac-aea1-aa610d5080c1}, type: Upgrade, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, dependency: None
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:06]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:06]i300: Apply begin
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:06]i010: Launching elevated engine process.
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:07]i011: Launched elevated engine process.
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:08]i012: Connected to elevated engine.
[29F0:2608][2018-09-24T11:42:08]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[29F0:2608][2018-09-24T11:42:08]i359: Paused automatic updates.
[29F0:2608][2018-09-24T11:42:08]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[29F0:2608][2018-09-24T11:42:08]i361: Created a system restore point.
[29F0:2608][2018-09-24T11:42:08]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{19af776a-0c57-4d9b-9cb3-f7b541bfe755}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[29F0:2608][2018-09-24T11:42:08]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\orhan12\AppData\Local\Temp\{16AAE7B9-F2C5-4923-952F-AF9F7AD27A3A}\.be\FlownetMasterSetup.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{19af776a-0c57-4d9b-9cb3-f7b541bfe755}\FlownetMasterSetup.exe'
[29F0:2608][2018-09-24T11:42:08]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {19af776a-0c57-4d9b-9cb3-f7b541bfe755}, version: 1.0.0.1
[29F0:2608][2018-09-24T11:42:08]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{19af776a-0c57-4d9b-9cb3-f7b541bfe755}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[29F0:2A84][2018-09-24T11:42:08]i305: Verified acquired payload: MyApplication at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\MyApplication, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{70ED3308-C6DB-43AA-B371-E739E4BD3D7D}v1.0.0.7\FlowNet Master.msi.
[29F0:2608][2018-09-24T11:42:08]i323: Registering package dependency provider: SQLServer2012Express,YOUR_INSTANCE, version: 11.0.3000.0, package: Sql2012Express
[29F0:2608][2018-09-24T11:42:08]i325: Registering dependency: {19af776a-0c57-4d9b-9cb3-f7b541bfe755} on package provider: SQLServer2012Express,YOUR_INSTANCE, package: Sql2012Express
[29F0:2608][2018-09-24T11:42:08]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {70ED3308-C6DB-43AA-B371-E739E4BD3D7D}, version: 1.0.0.7, package: MyApplication
[29F0:2608][2018-09-24T11:42:08]i301: Applying execute package: MyApplication, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{70ED3308-C6DB-43AA-B371-E739E4BD3D7D}v1.0.0.7\FlowNet Master.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7"'
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:19]i319: Applied execute package: MyApplication, result: 0x0, restart: None
[29F0:2608][2018-09-24T11:42:19]i325: Registering dependency: {19af776a-0c57-4d9b-9cb3-f7b541bfe755} on package provider: {70ED3308-C6DB-43AA-B371-E739E4BD3D7D}, package: MyApplication
[29F0:2608][2018-09-24T11:42:19]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{19af776a-0c57-4d9b-9cb3-f7b541bfe755}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[29F0:2608][2018-09-24T11:42:19]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{19af776a-0c57-4d9b-9cb3-f7b541bfe755}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:20]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: EulaAcceptCheckbox = 1
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: Netfx4FullVersion = 4.7.03062
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: Netfx4x64FullVersion = 4.7.03062
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: SqlInstanceKeyFound = 0
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 5
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: WixBundleFileVersion = 1.0.0.1
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 0
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\orhan12\AppData\Local\Temp\FLOWNETMASTER_20180924114204.log
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_MyApplication = C:\Users\orhan12\AppData\Local\Temp\FLOWNETMASTER_20180924114204_000_MyApplication.log
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = Melina-Aero
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = FLOWNETMASTER
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = C:\Users\orhan12\source\repos\PropulsimCS\Propulsim\FlownetMasterSetup\bin\Debug\FlownetMasterSetup.exe
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder = C:\Users\orhan12\source\repos\PropulsimCS\Propulsim\FlownetMasterSetup\bin\Debug\
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {19af776a-0c57-4d9b-9cb3-f7b541bfe755}
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_MyApplication = C:\Users\orhan12\AppData\Local\Temp\FLOWNETMASTER_20180924114204_000_MyApplication_rollback.log
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: WixBundleSourceProcessFolder = C:\Users\orhan12\source\repos\PropulsimCS\Propulsim\FlownetMasterSetup\bin\Debug\
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: WixBundleSourceProcessPath = C:\Users\orhan12\source\repos\PropulsimCS\Propulsim\FlownetMasterSetup\bin\Debug\FlownetMasterSetup.exe
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: WixBundleUILevel = 4
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 1.0.0.1
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i410: Variable: WixStdBALanguageId = 1033
[2074:1E98][2018-09-24T11:42:21]i007: Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No
```

Edit:I edited my code and deleted detect and installation condition it work it doesn't skip but why skip this conditions why not work?